# RxSwift not recognizing tableView modelSelected without long press

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I'm trying to call the `modelSelected` function with RxSwift on my UITableView, but for some reason, unlike any other UITableView I've implemented in my codebase, it doesn't recognize my tap gesture unless I hold down on the table view cell.

I have a table view that I have connected to my .xib file. In that .xib file, I have embedded my table view inside my UIViewController and have defined the layout for a prototype table view cell.

```
@IBOutlet private var tableView: UITableView!
```

And this is what I have in my `viewDidLoad` function.

```
viewModel.modelArray
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: CustomTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: CustomTableViewCell.self)) { row, element, cell in
                // Assign cell UI properties
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

tableView.rx.modelSelected(ModelClass.self)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] model in
                // Respond to cell tap
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Is there something I might be missing here?

Comment: Nothing is missing in the code you posted and it works properly. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: If you're using a simulator I find that sometimes UI glitches and touches don't register properly. Try killing the Simulator and running it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging around and speaking with the RxSwift team, I managed to find the root cause of this issue: there was a conflicting UIGestureRecognizer on this view controller.

I had assigned it to this view controller's `view` component, which was ultimately interfering with the tap gesture for the `modelSelected` function. So, while the `modelSelected` function for my table view was not necessarily being ignored, it would only be recognized after a long press.